# How can pass the Testcase name to the browserstack from RobotFramework? longside browser=${BROWSER} remote_url=${RemoteURL}?

Tags: robotframework, browserstack

when i pass

```
open browser  ${Url}  browser=${BROWSER}  remote_url=${remoteurl}  desired_capabilities=browser:${BROWSER},browser_version:${BROWSER_VERSION}
```

In the browser stack it just shows `${BROWSER}` and `${OS}`

[image]

How can i pass test case name ?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about what it is that you're trying to achieve? I'm having some trouble understanding what the goal is for the test case name in the screenshot. I'm assuming here that this is what you're after.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to name a session on BrowserStack. If yes, BrowserStack provides a capability "name" to do this. You can organize your tests using the project, build and name capabilities. You can name a test session, group similar test sessions into a build, and add a build to a project.

For example, in Java you can set the following capabilities in your test scripts:

```
caps.setCapability(“project”, “Project001”);
caps.setCapability(“build”, “Build_v1”);
caps.setCapability(“name”, “Login Test”);
```

No sure how this is done in Robotframework with Selenium. The above should give you a basic idea.

Comment: This was helpful . Yes i was using Robotframework with Selenium  i was building in python though . But i figured out the answer .Thank you !!  here is what i figured , we need to pass another parameter ${name} along with the desired capabilities . This works !!